Flutter App, I have an image path from user. But I need a Url link. So in web we use the Blob URLs createBlobUrl(), but how can i do this in my app
I used the image_picker package and got the iamge from user's phone which gives me a image.path but I need to send a url link to backend service, I can't just send a path of png. How can i use the createObjectUrlFromBlob() function in my ios app of flutter, or is there any other way to do that?
I don't know if webview is working on that or no, but if anyone did smthn like this problem.

If you want to upload the image to the backend, You can convert it to base64
